# Websocket concurrent connections limit on Heroku

Tags: heroku, websocket

How many websocket concurrent connections can a single Heroku dyno hold?

I'm running **Thin** as the web server on top of the **Cedar** stack with a **Ruby** framework.

Comment: Depends on the application.

Comment: In any case, there's an upper bound on Heroku's router of how many simultaneous requests it can handle.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

"You can maintain around 6,000 open connections on a single dyno
Creating more than 160 connections/sec will cause H11 errors (backlog too deep)"

Take a look to this link:

http://veldstra.org/2013/10/25/heroku-websocket-performance-test.html

Answer (score 3):

I asked support again (as the latest here was from 2016) and got a similar answer:

*There is no hard limit on the number of WebSocket connections per dyno, as you mentioned the limit is 50x connections per router. Giving you an exact figure is complicated as the number of available routers is not static. We have a Router layer that has many machines, and each router can track 50 connections to each Dyno in your app. Unfortunately, we don't publish the number of active routers as this figure scales as our platform reacts to the current inbound traffic.*

*1500 to 2000 is a decent average estimate with a theoretical upper bound somewhere in the range of 4500. Generally, once you have exhausted the number of concurrent connections, you'll start to receive H11 errors back from Heroku. If you're expecting thousands of concurrent users I would recommend having more than 1 dyno not just to increase the number of WebSocket connections but also because horizontal scaling would add some resiliency to your application.*

Answer (score 2):

I've got an answer from Heroku's support:

> Hi,
>   Our router will accept 50 simultaneous requests, after which it will send an H11 error.
>   This means each dyno can handle a maximum of 50 open websockets.
>   Please let us know if you still have any doubt or question.

Comment: Well, this is not right. I just tried this simple app: https://github.com/heroku-examples/ruby-ws-test opened 250 tabs with it (each tab will show a websocket connection open in heroku logs and remain open) and no H11 errors at all. Would be great to find a better way to find the limits. But surely more than 50.

Comment: I've removed the answer acceptance. If you ever find the real number, please share.

Comment: "There are no limitations on the free dyno tier in terms of resources. In terms of concurrent connections there is a theoretical limit of 50 connections per Heroku router instance but we don't currently publicise the number of router instances running at any one time. In general, for the EU region you can expect to have around 1500 connections available at any given time." --staff reply to me. Later he clarified, this limit is for all dyno types. even paid ones.

Answer (score 0):

This is also relevant (from 2021, Heroku documentation):

> ## Request concurrency
>
> Each router maintains an internal per-app request
> counter. On the Common Runtime, routers limit the number of concurrent
> requests per app. There is no coordination between routers however, so
> this request limit is per router. The request counter on each router
> has a maximum size of 200n (n = the number of web dynos your app has
> running). If the request counter on a particular router fills up,
> subsequent requests to that router will immediately return an H11
> (Backlog too deep) response.

— https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/http-routing#request-concurrency

See also: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/http-routing#simultaneous-connections